# Reading 32 bit registers on pymodbus

Tags: python, 32-bit, pymodbus

How can I read a 32 bit value from an address on one of my devices which I am communicating to via pymodbus please?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using pymodbus and I have a device which I am connected to via serial RTU and I need to read it's registers. I am able to read registers which are 16bit but I am not able to do so with registers which are 32bit. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

```py
    rr = client.read_coils(0, 32)
                           #start, number of bits

    index = 0
    for A in rr.bits:
        print("Bit " + str(index) + ":", A)
        index += 1
```

Take a look https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/common/synchronous_client.py

Comment: The poster is trying to read registers, not coils.

Answer (score 0):

As of 8 August 2023 `pymodbus` strictly adheres to the modbus standard which doesn't allow 32 bit registers. See [pymodbus GitHub discussion](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/issues/669).

Apparently [`enron-modbus`](https://github.com/u9n/enron-modbus) supports 32 bit registers, but as of 8 August 2023 it is no longer possible to install using `pip`.

(I have a device with 32 bit registers that I am trying to get to work with Home Assistant, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.)